# Thunderbird is not downloading all mail from the server

Tags: thunderbird

I have configured the Thunderbird client.

I have multiple folders configured on the server along with Inbox.
When I download mail from server, Thunderbird only downloads mail from the Inbox folder on the server.

Any idea why this is happening and what could be the possible solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem sounds like the standard IMAP problem:

By default IMAP is designed to look only in your INBOX for new mail. Especially when your server supports IMAP push/idle command you get an instant notification for new mail in your INBOX.

All the other folders are not checked by default. In Thunderbird you can selectively add folders Thunderbird should check for new mail (see folder property dialog) or you can specify to check for all folders by setting

```
mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new = true
```

in the Config Editor. Anyway the additional folder will only be checked every x minutes, depending on the IMAP account settings you have specified.

Comment: As per link http://kb.mozillazine.org/How_do_I_check_for_new_messages_in_other_folders I have set the configuration mail.server.default.check_all_folders_for_new to true as I could not find mail.check_all_imap_folders_for_new configration. Still my thunderbird is not fetching mails from other folders.Any idea what is happening ?